# How to replace several different characters by several others?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

This is what I tried without success:

```js
function replaceFunc() {
        let str = document.getElementById("test_string").value;
    
        let res = str.replace(/\s/g, "·").replace(/\n/g, "↵\n");
        document.getElementById("test_string").value = res;
      }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea type="text" id="test_string" name="test_string" onkeyup="replaceFunc()"></textarea>
 </form>
```

With this code, the newline replacement is not taking into account but is replaced by a dot like the space.

Comment: `\s` matches all whitespace, including linebreaks. You may want to use a literal space character instead.

Comment: @trincot No, because the second leaves the newlines, and `\s` will then remove them.

Comment: One problem that I can see that you will have is that you are replacing the new line with an arrow and a new line. So once there is a new line, on every keyup event, that new line will continue to be replaced with another arrow and new line, and the arrows will keep growing

Comment: Missed the newline in the replacement, @Barmar ,-)

Comment: @Steve Indeed this is what happened, any hint on how to solve this new problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to be fixed in each pass of the replace method.

---

##### First Pass

In the first replace you need to use an actual space character, and not the whitespace (`\s`) token.  This is because the `\s` token matches any space, tab or ***newline character*** and you don't want to target that in the first pass, or it will be replaced by the `"·"`.

```
.replace(/ /gm, "·")
```

https://javascript.info/regexp-character-classes

---

##### Second Pass

In the second pass, since you are firing this on every `onkeyup` event, once a `↵\n` replacement has occured, the `\n` part of that replacement, will continue to be replaced with another `↵\n`, and the arrows will keep growing every time an `onkeyup` event occurs.

To prevent this you need to use a Negative Lookbehind assertion so that it won't replace the `\n` that is immediately preceded by `↵`

```
.replace(/(?<!↵)\n/gm, "↵\n")
```

https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

---

I also added in the multi-line flag to make sure that all lines are evaluated.

See the snippet below, and let me know if you have any questions.

```js
function replaceFunc() {
        let str = document.getElementById("test_string").value;
    
        let res = str.replace(/ /gm, "·").replace(/(?<!↵)\n/gm, "↵\n");
        document.getElementById("test_string").value = res;
      }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea type="text" id="test_string" name="test_string" cols="50" rows="10" onkeyup="replaceFunc()"></textarea>
 </form>
```